# In jade how can I call a function without escaping the returned string?

Tags: go, pug

I'm using jade as part of a simple website using golang as the backend.

As part of this I have jade that looks like this:

```
p#{printf("%s", Body)}
```

I'm using the package github.com/go-floki/jade to compile this into an executable go template. The function printf is a go builtin that is run once the template is executed.

The problem is that I want unescaped html. The jade doc seems to indicate that this:

```
p!{printf("%s", Body)}
```

should work but that just ends up as:

```
<p>printf("%s", Body)}</p>
```

Is there a way to escape the function without escaping its argument?

Thanks, Zac

Comment: i think you should open an issue to golang jade package about this https://github.com/Joker/jade/issues

Comment: @nvartolomei Is this an issue? I didn't think of doing that because I thought I was missing something.

Comment: Zac Pullar-Strecker I think so, though not sure. At least in original jade implementation this works.